# How do I turn off Xcode Undefined Behavior Sanitizer

Tags: ios, xcode

How do I turn off the Undefined Behavior Sanitizer setting in the Scheme Manager in Xcode? I have a current app with an external library through Cocoapods that is generating this error and it's continually pausing my app. I'd like to turn off the Undefined Behavior Sanitizer option but it seems it's locked as per image below:

[image]

Currently running Xcode 9.3.1 on OS X 10.13.4

Comment: @matt I agree that it should not be disabled. But it's currently being generated by a 3rd party dependancies through Cocoapods and it's pausing our app every few seconds. Is there a way to make it not enabled for just the library? My project is a mixture of ObjC and Swift if that helps.

Comment: @matt Thanks for the comment. I'm not intentionally hiding details, I'm just not sure what details you're after as you never asked for specifics and I did not think it was particularly relevant to the question. I'm using a pod called `AeroGearOTP` used to generate a One Time Password that uses code from Google from their Authenticator. I've reached out to AeroGear in their own personal issue tracker, but to no avail. This is besides the point however. I did not think an external library would be responsible for my scheme's inability to deselect it, hence why I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 5):

As others have mentioned, the undefined behavior sanitizer is not available for Swift-only projects. If your project started out as a mixed Swift/Objective-C project, this setting can get stuck in the "on" position.

Normally this isn't a problem, but I've had issues with this when importing third party libraries. To turn off the UBS when it is grayed out in Xcode, go to your project file in Finder, control-click on it and select "Show Package Contents". Find all of your scheme configurations in the `xcsharedata` and the `xcuserdata` folders (they will have the `xcscheme` file extension).

Open these files in a text editor and find `enableUBSanitizer = "YES"` and replace it with `enableUBSanitizer = "NO"`. Save the files and the next time you open Xcode, the checkbox will be deselected.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to changing

```
enableUBSanitizer
```

to NO in the .xcproject -> Show Package Content -> in the .xcscheme files where it was located.

I had to change

```
enableASanStackUseAfterReturn
```

to NO as well in those files.

Which disabled my "Detect use of stack after return" - which was enabled as well - and grayed out.